# AtEndOfStream condition error in vbscript

Tags: loops, vbscript

I encounter a problem with a double loop in a vbs script.

This is the script:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sourceFile = fso.OpenTextFile("source.txt")
Set validFile = fso.OpenTextFile("valid.txt")
Set result = fso.CreateTextFile("result.txt", True)

Do while validFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
Wscript.echo validFile.AtEndOfStream
  validLine = validFile.ReadLine
  Do while sourceFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    sourceLine = sourceFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(sourceLine,validLine) > 0 then
        result.WriteLine(sourceLine)
    End if 
  Loop
sourceFile.Close
Loop
Wscript.echo "End of script"
result.close
validFile.close
```

The second Loop will not be reset at its end, so the next first loop start, it does nothing.
The sourceFile.AtEndOfStream return -1 unlike 0.
I have put sourceFile.Close wich seems to do a reset but nothing append.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

While you **can** read each line from one (source) file and loop over all lines of a second file (valid) to use each line in valid on each line in source by opening/closing valid in the outer loop, you `shouldn't`.

Load the content of valid into memory **before** you start the loop on source.

If you give some details about your real world problem - what do you want to check source for? - we could discuss **how** and **into what** to load valid.

Answer (score 1):

When you read a file in a loop, the cursor (i.e. the position in the file from which you currently read) doesn't magically return to the beginning of the file after the loop ends. Particularly not when you close the file after the loop (because then you don't even have a file anymore). You need re-open it before you can read it again. Also, I'd suggest using `Until condition` instead of `While condition <> true` as the former is much better readable than the latter:

```
Do Until validFile.AtEndOfStream
  validLine = validFile.ReadLine

  Set sourceFile = fso.OpenTextFile("source.txt")
  Do Until sourceFile.AtEndOfStream
    ...
  Loop
  sourceFile.Close
Loop
```

However, as [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20104492/1630171) pointed out, reading a file over and over again is usually not a good choice performance-wise. If at least one file is relatively small (compared to the available amout of RAM) it's better to read that file into an array and iterate over that array in the inner loop:

```
sourceText = Split(fso.OpenTextFile("source.txt").ReadAll, vbNewLine)

Do Until validFile.AtEndOfStream
  validLine = validFile.ReadLine
  For Each sourceLine In sourceText
    ...
  Next
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you're trying to do?

I can see at least one problem here right off. If you do `sourceFile.Close` then try to read it on the next loop, you won't be able to because it's closed.

Try moving this line
`Set sourceFile = fso.OpenTextFile("source.txt")`
right before this line in the script
`Do while sourceFile.AtEndOfStream <> True`

You'll be opening and closing the file at each loop, which is for each line in the `valid.txt` file. This doesn't seem like good practice, but if you explain what your goal is maybe I could help find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your help.
Indeed, I had not enough time to do things well but I have completely rewrite this little script with your suggestions and it works great!!

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set validFile = fso.OpenTextFile("valid.txt")
Set result = fso.CreateTextFile("result.txt", True)
sourceText = Split(fso.OpenTextFile("source.txt").ReadAll, vbNewLine)

Do until validFile.AtEndOfStream

  validLine = validFile.ReadLine

  For Each sourceLine In sourceText

    If InStr(sourceLine,validLine) > 0 then
        result.WriteLine(sourceLine)
    End if 

  Next

Loop

Wscript.echo "Fin du traitement"
result.close
validFile.close
```

Bye.